# Is there a way in TS to check if a function parameter is optional?

Tags: typescript, reflection

We can do this get get a function's params:

```js
function saySomething(thingToSay?: string) {
  console.log(thingToSay || 'Hello');
}
type ThingToSay = Parameters<typeof saySomething>[0]
```

Can we do something to figure out if ThingToSay is optional or not?
Something like this maybe? (I've made up the IsOptional utility type - does something like this exist)?

```js
type ThingToSayIsOptional = IsOptional<Parameters<typeof saySomething>[0]>
```

Comment: What precisely are you looking for when you want to examine a parameter? You could check if the parameter allows `undefined` as optional parameters would. However, `function foo(x: string | undefined)` also allows `undefined` and is *not* optional. However, it's not clear if that is enough here or not.

Comment: You expect `ThingToSayIsOptional` to be a boolean type, or..? Not sure what you would use that for... maybe expand the question? Either way, all [utility types are listed here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html)...

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/WPOLzm) meet your needs? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?